# Class name is wrong in Python code

Tags: python

Below is the code that I have generated using wxFormBuilder however when I tied to run the code its giving error.

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

class MyFrame2(wx.Frame):   #Class defined

    def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(
        self,
        parent,
        id = wx.ID_ANY,
        title = wx.EmptyString,
        pos = wx.DefaultPosition,
        size = wx.Size(1020, 486),
        style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL,
    )

self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

gbSizer1 = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 0)
gbSizer1.SetFlexibleDirection(wx.BOTH)
gbSizer1.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode(wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED)

self.m_textCtrl6 = wx.TextCtrl(
    self,
    wx.ID_ANY,
    wx.EmptyString,
    wx.DefaultPosition,
    wx.DefaultSize,
    0,
)
gbSizer1.Add(self.m_textCtrl6, wx.GBPosition(0, 0),
    wx.GBSpan(1, 1), wx.ALL, 5)

self.m_button4 = wx.Button(
    self,
    wx.ID_ANY,
    u 'MyButton',
    wx.DefaultPosition,
    wx.DefaultSize,
    0,
)
gbSizer1.Add(self.m_button4, wx.GBPosition(0, 1), wx.GBSpan(1,
    1), wx.ALL, 5)

self.SetSizer(gbSizer1)
self.Layout()

self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

def __del__(self):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame2(parent = None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Error msg is:Why I am getting error msg when I am trying to invoke the class.
I can see that MyFrame is defined but still getting below error.

NameError: name 'MyFrame2' is not defined

Any Help on this.

Comment: Please correct your indentation, it matters in Python.

Comment: In Python indentation is part of syntax. After you'll fix it code should work fine.